# Show $\lim\limits_{a \rightarrow + \infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+y^2}e^{-ay} dy =0 $

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Need to prove $\lim\limits_{a \rightarrow + \infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+y^2}e^{-ay} dy =0 $ and 
$\lim\limits_{a \rightarrow + \infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{y}{1+y^2}e^{-ay} dy =0 $

Can someone solve using dominated convergence theorem? I want to know how LDC is applied.

Comment: Dominated convergence theorem definitely gives you a single-line proof for the first one. Just observe that the integrands are dominated by an integrable function $(1 + y^{2})^{-1}$. But 5xum's idea is much easier to utilize in both of the problems.

Comment: Do you mean I just do Riemann integral? I am confused if Lebesgue is used in this problem.

Comment: @user220055 For continuous functions, there is no difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this:

$$0<\frac{1}{1+y^2}<1,$$
meaning that $$\frac{1}{1+y^2}e^{-ay} < e^{-ay}$$
and

$$\int _0^\infty\frac{1}{1+y^2}e^{-ay}dy < \int_0^\infty e^{-ay}dy$$

Comment: $\lim\limits_{a \rightarrow + \infty} cos (a)\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+y^2}e^{-ay} dy$ is in another problem. Is it legal to say it is 0? And do I need to prove continuity for the question I asked?

Comment: If $$\lim_{a\to\infty} f(a) = 0$$ and $g$ is a bounded function, then it is easy to see that $$\lim_{a\to\infty} f(a)g(a) = 0.$$

Comment: I kind remember this but was not sure.Thank you.

Comment: @user220055 If you are not sure, I advise you to try and prove the statement, it's not hard.

Comment: Could you please show me how LDC works in this question?

Comment: @user220055 What is LDC?

Comment: @5xum: [Lebesgue Dominated Convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). You need one dominating function as $a\to\infty$ (e.g. $e^{-y}$ for $a\ge1$)

Comment: @robjohn I understand. However, I think my answer is more than sufficient for the OP to figure the rest out by himself. He has, at least so far, shown no effort of his own, so I will not bother with this question any longer.

Comment: @5xum: Your answer is quite nice (I've upvoted it), but I was simply replying to the question. The LDC question is answered in the ["duplicate" question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/765086).