# Show $\lim\limits_{a \rightarrow + \infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{y}{1+y^2}e^{-ay} dy =0 $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

How to use LDC and MCT to prove?

Comment: I am seconding to close this question as a duplicate.  And, FYI, if you don't get an answer to a question, please do not re-post it; rather, you could either post a bounty or request someone else to post a bounty for you via chat.

Comment: I still need help though. I was told this is kind of different from the other one. If I want to use LDC, I can let $g=e^{-ay}$ for the other one, prove it is integrable, then bring limit inside. For this one, should I let $g=ye^{-ay}$ and do same thing? I also have trouble explain point wise condition ind LDC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit
$$
\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_0^\infty\frac{y}{1+y^2}e^{-ay}\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
can be handled by Dominated Convergence.

For $a\ge1$, $\frac{y}{1+y^2}e^{-ay}$ is dominated by $\frac12e^{-y}$ and
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac12e^{-y}\,\mathrm{d}y=\frac12
$$
Pointwise,
$$
\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac{y}{1+y^2}e^{-ay}=0
$$
therefore,
$$
\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_0^\infty\frac{y}{1+y^2}e^{-ay}\,\mathrm{d}y=0
$$

---

Note that you cannot dominate this integrand by $\frac{y}{1+y^2}$ since that function is not in $L^1$. However, $\frac{y}{1+y^2}\le\frac12$, so we can use $\frac12e^{-y}$ to dominate the integrand.

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head
(as usual),
I would split the integral
into two parts
divided,
somewhat arbitrarily,
at $1$.

Let
$I = \int_0^1$
and
$J = \int_1^{\infty}$.

$J < \int_1^{\infty} y e^{-ay} dy
= e^{-ay}(\frac{y}{-a}-\frac1{a^2})\big|_1^\infty
= -e^{-a}(\frac1{-a}-\frac1{a^2})
\to 0
$.

$I < \int_0^{1} y e^{-ay} dy
= e^{-ay}(\frac{y}{-a}-\frac1{a^2})\big|_0^1
= e^{-a}(\frac1{-a}-\frac1{a^2})-\frac1{a^2}
\to 0
$.

So $I+J \to 0$.

---

Looking at this,
you could just show that
$\int_0^{\infty} y e^{-ay} dy
\to 0$
and that would be enough.

Oh well. I'll leave the whole thing there.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\lim_{a \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}{y \over 1 + y^{2}}\expo{-ay}\,\dd y = 0
     :\ {\large ?}}$

> With $\ds{a > 0}$:
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large%
> 0<\verts{\int_{0}^{\infty}{y \over 1 + y^{2}}\expo{-ay}\,\dd y}}
> <\verts{\int_{0}^{\infty}y\expo{-ay}\,\dd y}
> \\[5mm]&={1 \over a^{2}}\verts{\int_{0}^{\infty}y\expo{-y}\,\dd y}={1 \over a^{2}}
> \stackrel{a\ \to\ \infty}{\Huge\to} \color{#66f}{\large 0}
> \end{align}